# python: несколько регулярных выражений

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки, поиск

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать следующий шаблон через регулярные выражения

есть несколько сумм/разностей произведения/частного нескольких чисел, причем числа могут быть отрицательными

например:

```
1+2*-3/-4-5
```

из которого надо выделить

`1`, `2*-3/-4`, `-5`

а из

```
1--2
```

выделить

```
`1`, `-2`
```

как я понимаю надо задать в шаблон по типу

```
([+-])?((([*\/]-)?[*\/.\d])+)
```

правило, что может входить и минус, но только если перед ним есть `[*\/]`, но как это реализовать не пойму

может как-то делается это элегантно

подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в итоге? Парсер арифметических выражений? Тогда не стоит тратить время на регулярки.

Comment: так как раз хочется регулярками
а почему не стоит тратить время?

Comment: Арифметические выражения со скобками не могут быть разобраны регулярками. Это классический результат. На практике это значит что регулярки не будут обрабатывать все случаи. Вы будете получать баг за багом, которые будете править усложняя регулярки, но это путь в никуда. Надо потратить час на токенайзер и алгоритм сортировочной станции и получить парсер, которые решит проблему раз и на всегда. Но, возможно, я просто фантазирую и у вас другая задача.